# setting action from navigation bar item created programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

My storyboard is like this:

[image: storyboard]

So from navigation controller , i am going to a tab controller.
My tab controller has its classed, named: MYTabBarView

In MyTabBarView.m , in its ViewDidLoad method I created the right bar button item programmatically like this:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(homeButtonAction)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=homeButton;
```

my question is how do I write an action for it. I mean if it was a button that was visible in the storyboard, I would "drag and dropped" it in the .h file and in the .m file I would have

the method:

Now what should I do?

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender {
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the selector you typed when you created the button:

```
- (void)homeButtonAction {
    // Code
}
```

And if you want to pass along the sender use `@selector(homeButtonAction:)` and the following method:

```
- (void)homeButtonAction:(id)sender {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error:
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainTabsController homeButtonAction]: unrecognized selector sent to

Comment: It works!! I hadn't seen the : inside the @selector. thanks!!